# Drawing in ios application

Tags: ios

I want to do drawing over uiimageview in ios.I am able to draw the drawing over the whole screen but I want to draw the drawing over specific area only.My Code is:-

```
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];    
    currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view]; //// tracing whatever ur finger touching the screen
    NSLog(@"%data",currentPoint);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake  (300,568)) ;  /// (300,568));   //// 320, 568, 480 iph4 screen ,568 ip5 screen
    [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0, 300,568)];    //(0,0, 300,568)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext (), kCGLineCapRound); // round line
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 18.0);  //// LINE WIDTH DIAMETER THE STROKE
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1, 1, 1, 1);  ///// RGB COLOUR
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());   ///// START WHEN WE DRAW THE PATH.
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);  /////
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

   // CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()) ;
  [drawImage setFrame:CGRectMake (0,0, 300, 568)]; //// (0, 0, 300,568)]; ///(100, 100, 150,280)];
    drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); ///// WHOLE UPPER PARA defined
UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); //// DONE DRAWING
lastPoint = currentPoint;  ////
```

Comment: which specific area ?

Comment: ... and you'd like help because?

Comment: I want to make drawing only over the ui image which is placed in the center of screen and having size as CGRectMake  ( 40, 80, 250, 290)];

Comment: trojanfoe,I am able to drawing if I giove the coordinates as CGRectMake(0,0, 300,568) but if i change these coordinates to CGRectMake ( 40, 80, 250, 290)],then we r n't able to draw properly...

Comment: You really think assuming the `UIImageView` is at exactly that location is the best thing to do?  Why don't you draw over the image displayed in the `UIImageView` or subclass it?

Comment: But I don't Know how to draw over the image displayed on UIIMAGEVIEW or subclass it.Can you Plz help me out...?

Answer (score 0):

Create a subclass of UIView and override `drawRect`

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // do your drawing here
}
```

Add your view as a subview to your UIImageView

```
MyCustomView *customView = [[MyCustomView alloc] initWithFrame:self.imageView.bounds];
[self.imageView addSubview:customView];
```

Update your view with the parameters you want to customize the drawing.